# connection between modularity and community result of CNM community detection

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis

anyone can give me an explanation about count modularity since I have this data

```
[(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,5),
(2,3),
(3,5),
(4,6),
(4,7),
(4,8)]
```

and still not get it when using CNM community detection the result is like this.
[result CNM modularity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXSUa.png)

The CNM code:

```
import numpy as np
from functions import is_connected

adj_mat = np.zeros((8,8))
with open('tes1.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for l in f:
        pair = l.replace('\n', '').split('\t')
        pair = (int(pair[0]), int(pair[1]))
        adj_mat[pair[0]-1, pair[1]-1] += 1
print adj_mat

community = {i: [i] for i in xrange(adj_mat.shape[0])}
m = np.sum(adj_mat) / 2
k = np.sum(adj_mat, axis=1)
print m
print community

delta_Q = np.zeros(adj_mat.shape)
for sort_idx, a in np.ndenumerate(adj_mat):
    if a > 0:
        delta_Q[sort_idx] = (1 / (2 * m)) - (k[sort_idx[0]] * k[sort_idx[1]] / ((2 * m)**2))

a = k / (2*m)
current_Q = 0

counter = 0
while len(community) > 2:
    max_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(delta_Q), delta_Q.shape)
    current_Q += delta_Q[max_idx]

    c_i = max_idx[0]
    c_j = max_idx[1]

    for c_k in community.iterkeys():
        if not (c_k == c_j or c_k == c_i):
            connected_to_i = is_connected(adj_mat, community[c_i], community[c_k])
            connected_to_j = is_connected(adj_mat, community[c_j], community[c_k])

            if connected_to_i and connected_to_j:
                delta_Q[c_j, c_k] = delta_Q[c_i, c_k] + delta_Q[c_j, c_k]
            elif connected_to_i:
                delta_Q[c_j, c_k] = delta_Q[c_i, c_k] - (a[c_j] * a[c_k])
            elif connected_to_j:
                delta_Q[c_j, c_k] = delta_Q[c_j, c_k] - (a[c_i] * a[c_k])

    delta_Q[:, c_j] = delta_Q[c_j, :].T
    delta_Q[c_i, :] = -np.inf
    delta_Q[:, c_i] = -np.inf

    a[c_j] += a[c_i]
    a[c_i] = 0

    community[c_j].extend(community[c_i])
    del community[c_i]

    print max_idx,
    print current_Q


    print community
```

when i count the modularity manually the result is different from result of the code. Plus, there are member of the community that not go in any of the community when running with zachary karate datasets. I think there are connection between wrong modularity that the code give and community member result.